# Fetch columns based on list in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a list List(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10, 8, 13) and I have a dataframe which read input from text file with no headers. I want to fetch the columns mentioned in my List from that dataframe(inputFile). My input files has more 20 column but I want to fetch only columns mentioned in my list

```
 val inputFile   = spark.read
  .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  .option("delimiter", "|")
  .load("C:\\demo.txt")
```

Comment: Next time, try to showcase what you have tried till now and if you faced any error. You can also take a look at [mcve] and [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the required columns using the following :

```
val fetchIndex = List(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10, 8, 13)

val fetchCols = inputFile.columns.zipWithIndex
                     .filter { case (colName, idx) => fetchIndex.contains(idx) }
                     .map(x => col(x._1) )

inputFile.select( fetchCols : _* )
```

Basically what it does is, `zipWithIndex` adds a continuous index to each element of the collection. So you get something like this :

```
df.columns.zipWithIndex.filter { case (data, idx) => a.contains(idx) }.map(x => col(x._1))
res8: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Column] = Array(companyid, event, date_time)
```

And then you can just use the *splat* operator to pass the generated array as varargs to the `select` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following steps to get the `columns` that you have defined in a `list` as indexes.

You can get the `column names` by doing the following

```
val names = df.schema.fieldNames
```

And you have a `list` of `column indexes` as

```
val list = List(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10, 8, 13)
```

Now you can `select` the `column names` that the indexes that the `list` has by doing the following

```
val selectCols = list.map(x => names(x))
```

Last step is to `select` only the `columns` that has been selected by doing the following

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col
val selectedDataFrame = df.select(selectCols.map(col): _*)
```

You should have the `dataframe` with column indexes mentioned in the `list`.

**Note:** *indexes in the list should not be greater than the column indexes present in the `dataframe`*